# Can't get django-star-ratings to display to template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-queryset

New to Django, feel like I'm close to figuring out where I'm going wrong here. I   have been trying to pass the context to my template to no avail. In models I have:

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    ratings =  GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name= 'object_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

And in views,

```
def RateList(request):
    queryset = Rate.objects.filter(ratings__isnull=False).order_by('ratings__average')
    context= {
        "object_list": queryset,
        "title": "List"
    }
    return render(request, 'UploadApp/upload.html', context)
```

and lastly, in my template I've put `{% ratings object_list %}` into the HTML as per the documentation. Not sure if I'm just overlooking some small detail, but I'm getting an `'str' object has no attribute 'meta'` error when I try and load the page. Any help is appreciated, I'm at the hair pulling stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method **__str__** you are returning **self.id**, but there is no field named **id** in your model,
So update your code like this :

```
class Rate(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    ratings =  GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name= 'object_list')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

One more thing, The **object_list** you are passing in context is a list of **Rate** model objects :

```
{% ratings object_list %}
```

This is the wrong method to show/iterate your data.

What you actually need in your template is:

```
{% for item in object_list %}

    {{ item.name }} and {{ item.ratings }}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! weirdly enough the documentation for django-star-ratings says 'To enable ratings for a model add the following tag in your template:{% load ratings %}
<html>
...
{% ratings object %}
...
</html> '   , So I'm guessing they've already created a function for passing it to the template or something. I did try as you suggested with the jinja , without luck.

Comment: @CrambleDrap Were you able to solve the **'str' object has no attribute 'meta'** problem by my answer??

Comment: @CrambleDrap You are mistaking {% ratings object %} as two different things, what it actually means is just an object of rating model.

Comment: @CrambleDrap You can just use {{ object_list }} to print it in the template.

Comment: oh yes, when I used the for loop the template was able to load, just without displaying anything. I'd added a few objects to the model through admin, and has seen elsewhere that the empty star ratings would show up  next to my list of objects. from looking at the docs I'd assumed that I'd just put in {% ratings object_list %} in my case, since thats the context i'd assigned it in the views. I wouldn't be surprised if ive totally misunderstood something somewhere, however

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135241/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-cramble-drap).